# How to use Native Android onClickListeners in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, sdk

I want to use a custom Android SDK which has a listener "BenefitInAppButtonListener" and has its own functions

this is how to normally use it in Android

```
checkoutBtn.setListener(object : BenefitInAppButtonListener {
    override fun onButtonClicked() {
        val benefitInAppCheckout = BenefitInAppCheckout.newInstance(
            this@MainActivity,
            ....,
            ....,
            ....,
            (object : CheckoutListener{
                override fun onTransactionSuccess(p0: Transaction?) {
                   Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                override fun onTransactionFail(p0: Transaction?) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

            })

        )

    }

    override fun onFail(p0: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }


})
```

Here We initialize a class called `BenefitInAppCheckout` by calling and `.newInstance()` and also pass in a CheckoutListener which is automatically called when compiled

So the issue is that I want to use this custom SDK in Flutter, but unable to call the `BenefitInAppButtonListener` since we don't have any view or button to setListener to

I tried to call the method directly, here is my code which calls the `onButtonClicked()` but doesn’t run the `CheckoutListener`

it seems that `BenefitInAppButtonListener` itself needs to be called otherwise the inner functions/Checkoutlistener doesn’t work

```
 var myListener = object : BenefitInAppButtonListener {
            override fun onButtonClicked() {

                Log.i("hamad2", paymentAmount) // this log does work

                val benefitInAppCheckout = BenefitInAppCheckout.newInstance(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    ...,
                    ...,
                    ...,
                    (object : CheckoutListener {
                        override fun onTransactionSuccess(p0: Transaction?) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Succ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }

                        override fun onTransactionFail(p0: Transaction?) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }

                    })

                )
            }
            override fun onFail(p0: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
        
        myListener.onButtonClicked();
```

Really appreciate the help!! Thanks

My whole flutter app's mainactivity.kt file:

```
package com.example.benefit_test

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import mobi.foo.benefitinapp.data.Transaction
import mobi.foo.benefitinapp.listener.BenefitInAppButtonListener
import mobi.foo.benefitinapp.listener.CheckoutListener
import mobi.foo.benefitinapp.utils.BenefitInAppButton
import mobi.foo.benefitinapp.utils.BenefitInAppCheckout

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    private val channel = "ummatisoftwares.benefitpay"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, channel).setMethodCallHandler {
                call, result ->
            if (call.method == "BenefitPay"){
                val amount = call.argument<String>("amount")
                val status = payBenefitApp(amount.toString())
                if (status == "Success") result.success("Success")
                else result.error("Error", status, null)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }

    }


    private fun payBenefitApp(paymentAmount: String): String {
        var status = "fail"

        var myListener = object : BenefitInAppButtonListener {
            override fun onButtonClicked() {
                Log.i("hamad2", paymentAmount)
                val benefitInAppCheckout = BenefitInAppCheckout.newInstance(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    ..., ..., ..., // some strings that are passed like 
                    (object : CheckoutListener {
                        override fun onTransactionSuccess(p0: Transaction?) {
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Suc", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            status = "Success"
                        }

                        override fun onTransactionFail(p0: Transaction?) {
                            status = " "+p0.toString()
                            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }

                    })

                )
            }
            override fun onFail(p0: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        myListener.onButtonClicked();

        return status
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Thanks, but the flutter documentation doesn’t mention anything about calling listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, create a button and then simply addListener to it
Finally call `button.performClick()` function

here is the example for with respective to my problem

```
val button = BenefitInAppButton(this@MainActivity)
button.setListener(object: BenefitInAppButtonListener {
    override fun onButtonClicked() {
        val benefitInAppCheckout = BenefitInAppCheckout.newInstance(
            this@MainActivity,
            ...,
            ...,
        )
    }
})

button.performClick()
```